# Efficient randomness reduction using k-wise independence

Tags: randomized-algorithms, derandomization, k-wise-independence

Consider a randomized algorithm with runtime $n$, which succeeds with high probability. The algorithm uses $O(n)$ uniformly random bits.

Now it is given that we can replace these uniformly random bits by $k$-wise independent bits, where $k$ depends on $n$ (say $k = \sqrt{n}$). Can we then reduce the number of random bits to $\tilde{O}(k)$ while keeping a runtime $\tilde{O}(n)$?

Clearly we could use k-wise independent bit generators (such as a random polynomial). However, naively implementing this would cost $\tilde{O}(k)$ steps per call, potentially increasing the runtime to $\tilde{O}(n k)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You can generate a random polynomial of degree $k$, then evaluate this polynomial at $n$ different points in $\tilde{O}(n)$ time using the DFT (the DFT lets you evaluate a polynomial of degree $n$ at $n$ different points in $\tilde{O}(n)$ time).

Comment: Is this easy to see for $n$ arbitrary points? Anyway a formal proof seems to be given in the paper "Fast modular transforms via division" by Moenck and Borodin (SWAT '72).

Comment: @smapers, no, it doesn't work for arbitrary points (as far as I know).  But for this application you don't need to evaluate the polynomial at arbitrary points; it suffices to evaluate it at any $n$ points that are convenient.  If you found a citation, I encourage you to write an answer of your own providing a reference to this result.

Comment: You need to evaluate the polynomial at $n$ points of the field $F_p$ for some prime $p \geq n$ (so $n$ distinct integers). Am I correct that DFT only allows to evaluate the polynomial at the $n$ roots of unity?

Comment: @smapers, Yes.  The DFT works over finite fields, too; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)#Number-theoretic_transform.